# Deserialise Json Array Windows Phone 8.0

Tags: c#, json, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, json.net

my JsonArray is

```
   [
  {
    "A": "asdasd",
    "B": "asdasd",
    "C": "43543543",
    "D": "fdgdfgt54654",
    "E": "54tg54g54g"
  },
  {
    "A": "45tg54tg54g",
    "B": "g45erg45g",
    "C": "rhtfg4hg4g",
    "D": "hdfhg45yg",
    "E": "fgh45yg45"
  },
  {
    "A": "trh4yh45yg",
    "B": "gy45g4554egt5",
    "C": "54hg4rg45g",
    "D": "gtrg45g",
    "E": "fdg54g45g545454"
  }

]
```

And My Class is

```
public class RootObject
{
    public string A { get; set; }
    public string B { get; set; }
    public string C { get; set; }
    public string D { get; set; }
    public string E { get; set; }
}
```

I am not able to deserialise this json array into RootObject Class...so please help...I have tries by accessing the individual members of array but that wasw very long method...so please help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your json object contains a list of the object you want to deserialize.

Basically you need to tell the deserializer that you have a List of your root objects, ie `List<RootObject>` then once you deserialize to this object you can iterate over each of the items in it.

Something like this works:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization; // Contains JavaScriptSerializer from System.Web.Extensions

namespace Tester
{
    static class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            deserialize();
        }

        public static void deserialize()
        {

            string jsonRaw = @"[
            {
                'A': 'asdasd',
                'B': 'asdasd',
                'C': '43543543',
                'D': 'fdgdfgt54654',
                'E': '54tg54g54g'
            },
            {
                'A': '45tg54tg54g',
                'B': 'g45erg45g',
                'C': 'rhtfg4hg4g',
                'D': 'hdfhg45yg',
                'E': 'fgh45yg45'
            },
            {
                'A': 'trh4yh45yg',
                'B': 'gy45g4554egt5',
                'C': '54hg4rg45g',
                'D': 'gtrg45g',
                'E': 'fdg54g45g545454'
            }
        ]";

            List<RootObject> rObjects = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<List<RootObject>>(jsonRaw);
            foreach (var o in rObjects)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(o.A + ", " + o.B + ", " + o.C + ", " + o.D + ", " + o.E);
            }
        }
    }

    public class RootObject
    {
        public string A { get; set; }
        public string B { get; set; }
        public string C { get; set; }
        public string D { get; set; }
        public string E { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Above code outputs:

```
asdasd, asdasd, 43543543, fdgdfgt54654, 54tg54g54g
45tg54tg54g, g45erg45g, rhtfg4hg4g, hdfhg45yg, fgh45yg45
trh4yh45yg, gy45g4554egt5, 54hg4rg45g, gtrg45g, fdg54g45g545454
```

Answer (score 2):

Your class should be:

```
public class RootObject
{
    public string details { get; set; }
    public string deal { get; set; }
    public string company_name { get; set; }
    public string validity { get; set; }
    public string coupon { get; set; }
}
```

Deserialize json string:

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(json string);
```

Comment: I think you meant `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>` instead

Comment: I tried it give following error
Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'App13.RootObject1' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly

Answer (score 0):

```
var syncEntitiesArray = [{"EntityName":"Bulletins","LastSyncDate":"20150525_072418"},{"EntityName":"DatasetFilters","LastSyncDate":"20150525_072418"},{"EntityName":"Datasets","LastSyncDate":"20150525_072418"},{"EntityName":"DatasetItems","LastSyncDate":"20150525_072418"}]

public class DateModel
{
    public string EntityName { get; set; }
    public string LastSyncDate { get; set; }
}

IList<DateModel> myObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IList<DateModel>>(syncEntitiesArray);

foreach (var obj in myObject)
  {
       string nodeName = obj.EntityName;
       string nodeValue = obj.LastSyncDate;
  }
```

This works perfect for me. Hope this helps you as well. Thanks!